# Cell Array to Array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array with 5 cells as shown beblow

```
<18250x1 int32> <18250x1 int32> <18250x1 int32> <18250x1 double> <18250x1 double>
```

In each cell, there are numbers of 18250 rows and 1 column.

Now I want to calculate the average of each row in cells 4 and 5, resulting another cell of <18250x1 double>.

I think the best way is to convert the cell array to array. But the function cell2mat only allows the array to have the same data types. I need to maintain the data types of int or double in the output. Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
James.

Comment: If you want to average cells 4 and 5 (and given that both are doubles), why would you run into issues of data types if you average them as `0.5 * (whatever{4} + whatever{5})`.

Comment: Isn't `(c{4}+c{5})/2` enough? Or `mean(horzcat(c{4:5}),2)` if you need  an arbitrary number of cell indices

Comment: Thanks, Nitish and Luis. Yes. Those you mentioned are easy solutions. I was stupidly wrong in using (C(4)+C(5))/2, and got an error message, saying that plus is not supported.